# Node Preview not working for anonymous users drupal 7

Tags: nodes, entities

I want Anonymous users to post Events on my site and moderators can moderate and publish it. I have set "Preview before Submitting" option  to "Required". Preview is not working for anonymous users. It does not display node preview on top and not giving "Save" option at the end of page.

Is this Drupal default behavior or some misconfiguration?

Comment: It could be a problem with your theme, are you using the default drupal theme?

Comment: I am using Zen starter theme and has created a custom theme using it. If a user is logged in, it displays preview and save button with the same theme.

Comment: I also checked it by switching to "Garland" theme without success.

Comment: Check permissions. Does anonymous users have "View own unpublished content"?

Comment: I tried giving "View own unpublished content" to anonymous users as per your comment. But it is still the same.

Comment: I don't think that Drupal architecture is really made to let anonymous users work with content (even though the permissions part should do the trick, I've had a lot a problem with that in the past)

Comment: I agree with you kevin. But say for general example, we created forum with Drupal and let anonymous can post message to forum. How to force preview it before saving. In my case, anonymous can post/propose events to the calendar, which can be published only after moderation.

Comment: Still an "issue" in D8. Tried to make a content type available for anonymous users to make instances of, with the ability to preview before publish. The node are not stored before preview resulting in a 404. Still trying to solve this with no luck. Works nice if I publish directly. Thinking of opening the site for user registrations as a "workaround".

Comment: I have disabled preview for that particular content type. Now anonymous user can save node directly without preview step.

Comment: Has anyone reported on d.o?